# Security for my android phone which is steal by someone

Tags: android-security

How can i track someone who steal my phone by doing something previous work before stealing .Can i able to activate some programming on it which can be unbreakable even the thief reset phone .

Thanks .

Comment: Call your local police station and report them

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that a good theft will manage to break or remove all kinds of security apps,etc. Although you can try using this one: [Clean Master](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.security&hl=en_US). To my mind if your smartphone has got a security app built-in, like Sony Xperia does, you can turn it on so that you can track your phone in case it is stolen.